# Подсчет элементов и проверка на выполнение условия Stream api

Tags: java, java-8

Имеется Stream, содержащий несколько ArrayList. Необходимо подсчитать сумму значений определенного int параметра объекта SomeObject, среди всех этих объектов в списке. После чего проверить, превышает ли сумма определенное значение. Если сумма больше, то выполнить определенное действие. При любом исходе нужно переключиться на следующий массив.

Comment: добавляйте свое решение (пусть даже неполное)

Comment: Правильно ли я понял задачу? Есть стрим, элементы которого - `List<SomeObject>`, а `SomeObject` содержит целое поле `someInt` и нужно пробежаться по стриму, посчитать сумму `someInt` элементов и если она больше `N`, выполнить какой-то `action`? Если так, то должно ли это действие зависеть от элементов исходного стрима, например, напечатать его элементы? Или просто в виде действия вывести типа `еще один лист с суммой больше N`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void doActionOnSomeObjectsWithSumGreaterThan(int number, Consumer<? super Map.Entry<List<SomeObject>, Integer>> action) {
    listStream.collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), summingInt(someObjects -> someObjects.stream()
            .mapToInt(SomeObject::getSomeInt).sum())))
            .entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > number)
            .forEach(action);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 8;
    Consumer<? super Map.Entry<List<SomeObject>, Integer>> action = entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    new StreamListSum().doActionOnSomeObjectsWithSumGreaterThan(number, action);
}
```